# CakePHP - Related models in a relationship table, displaying in a drop down?

Tags: php, cakephp

Given the following table structures:

Registered Participant model:

```
<?php
class RegisteredParticipant extends AppModel {
var $name = "RegisteredParticipant";
var $primaryKey = "id";
var $belongsTo = array(
  'EventLocation' => array('className' => 'EventLocation'),
  'RegistrationStatus' => array('className' => 'RegistrationStatus'),
  'Specialty' => array('className' => 'Specialty')
);
var $hasMany = array(
  'DietaryRestriction' => array('className' => 'DietaryRestriction')
);
}
?>
```

Event Location model:

```
<?php
class EventLocation extends AppModel {
   var $name = 'EventLocation';
   var $primaryKey = 'id';
   var $belongsTo = array(
      'Event' => array('className' => 'Event', 'foreignKey' => 'event_id'),
      'Location' => array('className' => 'Location', 'foreignKey' => 'location_id')
   );
}
?>
```

When I do this in my view:
     echo $form->input('RegisteredParticipant.EventLocation.moderator');

It returns a dropdown list of the `EventLocation.id`s, not the `EventLocation.moderators` like I expected. Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

nobody mentioned adding the `$displayField` to the model like this.

```
class EventLocation extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'EventLocation';
    var $displayField = 'moderators';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Event' => array('className' => 'Event', 'foreignKey' => 'event_id'),
        'Location' => array('className' => 'Location', 'foreignKey' => 'location_id')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duh. `$this->RegisteredParticipant->EventLocation->find()` wasn't using 'all' as it's param.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find('list') for dropdowns. E.g:

```
$locations = $this->RegisteredParticipant->EventLocation->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('some_fields')
));
$this->set('locations', $locations);
```

You will get back an array like:

```
array(
    'id_1' => 'some_field_contents',
    'id_2' => 'some_field_contents',
    'id_3' => 'some_field_contents'
);
```

Which can be handled on your view automatically by the Form helper.